# Does Flink Broadcast State allow to implement a Rule based on Time Window?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a use case: Suppose I want to make a rule that all events which were generated from a certain IP within 5 min time interval should go to a particular topic; I can have several such rules in my Broadcast state.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing this with one of Flink's built-in windows might be a bit tricky, because you would need to distribute the logic across different functions, i.e., the broadcast function and the window function.

However, you can implement the windowing logic also in a `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` alone. It provides a `TimerService` (to register timers and look up the current time) and keyed state, such that all required logic can be implemented. The broadcast input is then used to configure the behavior.

In fact, you might not even need a broadcast function, if rules are always applied per key, i.e., IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But no, Rules are dynamically given by a user like an sql query and to be applied on the event stream.

Comment: Is there any other way I can achieve this in flink?

Comment: Why does implementing the logic in one (or more) `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`s not work?

Comment: Might be he doesn't have a key I am guessing.